# Prime number between $n$ and $n!+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to prove that ($\forall \ n\in\mathbb{N}$) there exists a prime number $q$ such that $n < q \le 1 + n!$

I have made a graph with $n=0$ through $n=10$ and found solutions to all of them looking for a pattern and I see that $n!$ gets enormous fast and it becomes quite obvious that there is a prime number in between them.

I have considered trying to prove by contradiction that $q$ does not exist on that interval, but I don't know where to go from that statement.  Could anybody help me figure it out?  I have been staring at it for hours and I can't figure out where to go.

Thank you.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180204081557/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62825.html)

Answer (score 43):

Hint: $n!+1$ has some prime factor $p$. If $p \leq n$ then $p\mid n!$.

Comment: wow.. nice answer +1. Your answe is better than my one.

Comment: I am looking at this, and I do not know what math to use.  I cannot figure out what the first step would be, do I use a contradiction? then what do I do after I am stating a contradiction?

Is it that since n! and 1+n! are not divisible then there must be a prime number p that is greater than n that is a factor of n!+1?

I'm sorry I did not mean to enter the comment before I said that

Comment: @Sam You'll have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: I'm not clear about something, maybe it's just me. The requirement was that we find a prime $p \ni \exists n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n < p < n! + 1$. However, then we may not take $p \leq n.$

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId You too will have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId What does "$p \ni \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$" mean? And the requirement was $n<p\leq n!+1$, not $n<p<n!+1$.

Comment: OK, to clarify - if $n!+1$ is prime, then we are done. If not, then suppose $q$ is one of its factors. $q<n!+1$ obviously. Now if $q<=n$, then both $q|n!+1$ (assumption above) and $q|n!$ (definition of $n!$). But this is not possible, therefore $q>n$.

Comment: @JuliaHayward Right, that's the idea. You don't even need to single out the case that $n!+1$ is prime, since even prime numbers have a prime factor.

Comment: @JiK Thanks for pointing that out. The statement "$p \ni \exists n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$" means $p$ such that for some $n$ in $\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: then what you wrote was not at all the requirement. The statement to prove is $\forall n \exists$ prime $p : n < p \leq n! + 1$. (: is more common for "such that." $\ni$ means "contains the element.")

Comment: @Kundor It seems I wasn't paying much attention when I wrote that down, but the main point still remains. We may not pick $p \leq n$. Though, Yuval had in mind that we show $p > n$ by contradiction.

Answer (score 13):

HINT:
Use the [Bertrand's postulate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)
Since $n!\ge 2n$ for all $n\ge 3$ we have the result.

Comment: This is overkill.

Comment: If by "large $n$" you mean "$n > 3$", then, sure..

Comment: The OP was looking for a way to prove the statement from scratch, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

All the primes dividing $n!$ give remainder $1$ when they divide $n!+1$. Those include all primes from $1$ to $n$. So either $n!+1$ is itself a prime, or it is divisible by a prime $>n$ and of course $\le n!+1$.

Answer (score 4):

For $n=1$ and $n=2$ the condition holds.

So to prove the statement assume $n>2$. Now for every integer $x$ such that $1<x<(n+1),$ we have $x|n!$ and $x\not|(n!-1).$

$\therefore$ either $(n!-1)$ is a prime, or $\exists$ a prime $p\ge (n+1) $ such that $p|(n!-1)$.

So in any case, $\exists$ a prime $p$ such that $(n+1)\le p\le (n!-1)$.

$\therefore$  $\exists$ a prime number $p$ such that $n<p≤1+n!$ $\hspace{.2cm}$$,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$

Answer (score 4):

$n!+1$ isn't divisible by the integers from $2$ to $n$. Then all its prime factors exceed $n$, and there is at least one.

Answer (score 3):

Case 1) if n=1,2,3 then $q=2,3,7$

Case 2) for other n, $2n< n! $ Now we know $\exists q$ prime s.t $n<q<2n<1+n!$

Hence we are done.

Comment: This is precisely Nilan's answer.

Comment: Yeah I have just seen.