# A direct proof that there is a prime between $n$ and $n^2+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove there is a prime between $n$ and $n^2+1$ without using [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) or [Prime number theorem.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXpveguIjQAhWpjFQKHWuWAFMQFggtMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPrime_number_theorem&usg=AFQjCNHYNEK9f2CSkswNeivg23wo4v_w9g)

Do you have any idea?

Yuval Filmus's answer for [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946517/prime-number-between-n-and-n1/946525#946525) provides a quite useful idea.

But since $n^2+1\lt n!$ for $n\ge4$,  I do not know how to use it for this question.

Comment: The prime number theorem, in its simplest form, doesn't prove this. It only proves that _eventually_, if $n$ is big enough, it will hold.

Comment: We can prove it using Mertens' first theorem. That settles it for $n \geqslant e^4$, and the remaining cases are easy to do by hand. We can also prove something stronger with a little less work than proving Mertens' theorem requires, $x/2 < \vartheta(x) < 2x$ gives you a prime between $n$ and $4n$. Would you consider using Mertens' theorem or bounds for $\vartheta$ "direct"?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I am not familiar with those theorems. I am looking for a proof using some simple argument. Any way, Thank you for the useful comment. I will look at those theorems.

Comment: Note tht if $n$ isn't prime and the property holds for $n-1$, that it will also hold for $n$. So we only have to prove it for when $n$ is prime and then the lowest value (which is $2$, also a prime, so we don't realy need to do this).

Comment: @Nil it's not a proof, you still need to prove for all primes. And yes, you could reduce Bertrand's postulate to: for all primes $p$  there exists a prime $q$ such that $p<q<2p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to find (or at least prove the existence of) a positive integer $K = K(n)$ having a prime factor between $n$ and $n^2+1$.

For a prime $p$ and a postivie integer $k$, let $v_p(k)$ denote the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $k$, i.e. $v_p(k)$ is characterised by $p^{v_p(k)} \mid k$ and $p^{v_p(k)+1} \nmid k$. Next recall Legendre's formula

$$v_p(n!) = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \biggl\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{\ell}}\biggr\rfloor = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\bigl\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log p}\bigr\rfloor} \biggl\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{\ell}}\biggr\rfloor$$

for the prime factorisation of the factorials. Much of Legendre's formula generalises to arbitrary (increasing) arithmetic progressions. If we have an arithmetic progression

$$A_m = a + m\cdot d$$

with $a \geqslant 0$ and $d > 0$, then for every $r$ coprime to $d$ exactly one of every $r$ consecutive terms of the progression is a multiple of $r$. Let $\mu_r(k)$ denote the number of multiples of $r$ among $A_1, A_2, \dotsc, A_k$. Without any special knowledge about $d$ and $r$ we cannot pin down $\mu_r(k)$ exactly, but we know that for $r$ coprime to $d$ we have

$$\biggl\lfloor \frac{k}{r}\biggr\rfloor \leqslant \mu_r(k) \leqslant \biggl\lceil \frac{k}{r}\biggr\rceil.$$

By the same argument that shows Legendre's formula we can, for the "A-orial"

$$P_k = \prod_{m = 1}^k A_m,$$

see that

$$v_p(P_k) = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \mu_{p^{\ell}}(k)$$

for all primes $p$. For primes not dividing $d$, although we cannot give an explicit exact form for $v_p(P_k)$, we have pretty reasonable bounds, namely

$$\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\bigl\lfloor \frac{\log k}{\log p}\bigr\rfloor} \biggl\lfloor \frac{k}{p^{\ell}}\biggr\rfloor \leqslant v_p(P_k) \leqslant \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\bigl\lfloor \frac{\log A_k}{\log p}\bigr\rfloor} \biggl\lceil \frac{k}{p^{\ell}}\biggr\rceil,$$

since evidently $\mu_r(k) = 0$ for $r > A_k$.

Now let's come to the proof that for $n > 1$ there is always a prime strictly between $n$ and $n^2$ (for $n = 1$ we need the extra $+1$). Fix $n \geqslant 2$, and let $p_s$ be the largest prime not exceeding $n$, so $p_s \leqslant n < p_{s+1}$. Consider the arithmetic progression

$$A_m = 1 + m \cdot p_s$$

and let $k = p_s - 1$. On the one hand, we have

$$P_k = \prod_{m = 1}^k A_m > \prod_{m = 1}^k (A_m - 1) = p_s^{k}\cdot k!\,.\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, we have $A_k = p_s(p_s - 1) + 1 = p_s^2 - p_s + 1 < p_s^2$ and thus by the above

$$v_p(P_k) \leqslant \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\bigl\lfloor 2 \frac{\log p_s}{\log p}\bigr\rfloor}\biggl\lceil \frac{k}{p^{\ell}}\biggr\rfloor \leqslant \biggl\lfloor 2\frac{\log p_s}{\log p}\biggr\rfloor + \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \biggl\lfloor \frac{k}{p^{\ell}}\biggr\rfloor = \biggl\lfloor 2\frac{\log p_s}{\log p}\biggr\rfloor + v_p(k!)$$

for all primes $p \neq p_s$, hence

$$\prod_{p < p_s} p^{v_p(P_k)} \leqslant \prod_{p < p_s} \Bigl( p_s^2\cdot p^{v_p(k!)}\Bigr) = p_s^{2(s-1)}\cdot k!\,.\tag{2}$$

Also, none of the $A_m$ is divisible by $p_s$, whence $v_{p_s}(P_k) = 0$. Therefore it follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that

$$\prod_{p \leqslant n} p^{v_p(P_k)} < P_k$$

and consequently $P_k$ has a prime factor larger than $n$ as soon as $2(s-1) \leqslant k = p_s-1$, or equivalently $p_s \geqslant 2s - 1$. Which in fact holds for all $s$. And since a prime factor of $P_k$ divides at least one $A_m, \, 1 \leqslant m \leqslant k$ it follows that all prime factors of $P_k$ are $\leqslant A_k < p_s^2 \leqslant n^2$. So for $n \geqslant 2$ there always is at least one prime $q$ satisfying $n < q < n^2$ (or, slightly more tightly, $n < q \leqslant n^2 - n + 1$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful solution and great effort.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt 1 (failure):

Since $n^2+1$ is an integer, there exists some prime $p\le n^2+1$ such that $p\mid n^2+1$.

Suppose by way of contradiction we have $p<n$ for all $p\mid n^2+1$. Then $p\mid n^2$. But then $p\not\mid n^2+1$, because $n^2+1=kp+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thus for some $p\mid n^2+1$ we must have $n\le p\le n^2+1$.

Why does this not work? @Daniel Fischer points out that $n=7$ is a counterexample. All the primes that divide $n^2+1=50=2\cdot 5^2$ are smaller than $7$ and none of them divide $n^2$.

Comment: $p < n$ doesn't imply $p \mid n^2$. Consider $n = 7$, with $n^2+1 = 2\cdot 5^2$, all primes dividing $7^2+1$ are smaller than $7$.

Comment: Point taken, but if we replace $n^2$ with $n!$ then the logic works, right?

Comment: Yes, it works for $n!+1$. But that's much larger than $n^2+1$ except for small $n$.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my post to take note of your exception, but I don't know how to fix it yet, so I will leave it here until I can or someone else puts the right answer up.

Comment: I wonder what stipulation on $n$ (that it be composite, for example) might be enough to fix my argument. It still wouldn't be an answer to OP's question, but it might fix my flaw?

Comment: Composite doesn't help, $18^2 + 1 = 325 = 5^2\cdot 13$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Glad to learn something new at least.